# Max date of column with grouping

Tags: sql, max

I have a data set which is returning 3 rows because each row is linked to a position data table with job history.  How do I get the SQL to return just the one row with the highest date to?

```
select r.resource_id,
r.date_from as 'Resource Date From',
r.date_to AS 'Resource Date To',
p.post_id,
p.date_from AS 'Position Date From',
MAX(p.date_to) AS 'Position Date To'
from ahsresources r
    inner join aprresourcepost p on r.resource_id = p.resource_id and r.client = p.client
    where r.resource_typ = 'E'
    and r.resource_id = '10-1002595'
        GROUP BY r.resource_id, r.date_from, r.date_to, p.post_id, p.date_from, p.date_to
```

I've tried HAVING clauses, putting the SQL into the where.

The result looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `row_number() over()`  to assign 1 to the most recent dates, then restrict the joined rows to only those:

```
SELECT *
FROM ahsresources r
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT p.resource_id, p.post_id, p.date_to AS 'Position Date To'
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.resource_id, p.post_id
            ORDER BY p.date_to DESC) AS row_num
  FROM aprresourcepost p
  WHERE p.client = r.client
) AS derived_table ON r.resource_id = derived_table.resource_id 
AND derived_table.row_num = 1
WHERE r.resource_typ = 'E' AND r.resource_id = '10-1002595';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the below query. This query will retrieve the rows with the highest `date_to`, which mean that there is `NOT EXISTS` other rows that have the same `post_id` and `date_to` larger than its `date_to`.

```
SELECT r.resource_id,
       r.date_from    AS 'Resource Date From',
       r.date_to      AS 'Resource Date To',
       p.post_id,
       p.date_from    AS 'Position Date From',
       p.date_to      AS 'Position Date To'
FROM   ahsresources r
       INNER JOIN aprresourcepost p
               ON r.resource_id = p.resource_id AND r.client = p.client
WHERE  r.resource_typ = 'E' AND r.resource_id = '10-1002595'
       AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM  aprresourcepost p1
           WHERE p1.post_id = p.post_id AND p1.date_to > p.date_to)
```